# How do I traverse a directory in Mozilla Firefox 4.0 and beyond?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, directory, traversal

Used to do it like this:

```js
// Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before  
var ext = this.Cc["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
              .getService(this.Ci.nsIExtensionManager)
              .getInstallLocation(id)
              .getItemLocation(id); 

// list all XML files in the installation folder:
var entries = ext.directoryEntries;
var files = [];

while(entries.hasMoreElements())
{ )
```

How do I get the `ext` variable now?  I have gotten as far as the following:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");  
AddonManager.getAddonByID(id, function(addon) {
  ext = addon.getResourceURI("");  }
```

But not sure how to actually get the directory info to traverse it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might not be a directory to traverse - starting with Firefox 4 the extensions are no longer unpacked when you install them, so the resource URI will point to an XPI file (via `jar:` protocol scheme). Then again, in some cases the extension will be unpacked upon installation, then you will get a `file:///` URI. So you should do something like this (untested):

```js
var uri = addon.getResourceURI("");
if (uri instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIJARURI)
{
  var xpiFile = uri.JARFile.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL).file;
  var reader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/libjar/zip-reader;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIZipReader);
  reader.init(xpiFile);
  var enumerator = reader.findEntries(null);
  while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
  {
    var entry = enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIZipEntry);
    alert(entry.name);
  }
  reader.close();
}
else if (uri instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)
{
  var dir = uri.file;
  var enumerator = dir.directoryEntries;
  while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
  {
    var entry = enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    alert(entry.path);
  }
}
else
  throw new Error("Unexpected install location");
```